# Syntax highlighting when pasting into emails

Tags: html, email, vim, syntax-highlighting, paste

Im in the situation that I often send small codesnippets and xml-snippets to coworkers and partners via my outlook. 
Has anyone got a good idea or tool that I can use to have my pastes syntaxhighlighted before I paste them into an email.

I was thinking of an intermediate paste to "$fancytool" and then I would have something to copy that will htmlified so I can copy paste it into the "compose email" window.

*Edit-More-info:*

Im pasting from windows within a VMWare virtual Machine, it might be eclipse, xmlspy, logfiles and other programs

*Even-more-info:*

I've seen [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Pasting_code_with_syntax_coloring_in_emails) how to do it from Vim. Unfortunately it seldom from vim im copying Code, and my email machine hasnt got any vim. The vmware machines has gvim, but I was hoping for an easier way that pasting to vim, saving to file, opening in internetexplorer and then copy/paste

Comment: Sorry. My question didnt contain info enough. I have updated it with abit more info about what im pastin from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Late but I can give an answer that works.
You need 2 things

1. putty
2. access to some Unix server (With vim)

In putty options, Under window → selection , turn the check box on for

`Paste in to clipboard in RTF as well as plain text`.

Log on to the  server using putty.
start vim by typing vim
Paste your text (for example XML ) in to vim.
enter command mode (of vim by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>) and type
`:set syn=xml`.

Syntax highlighting kicks in.
Copy the text using mouse and paste it into your email.

Answer (score 5):

5 years too late, sorry, but I've a much simpler solution than the accepted answer.

Use this online tool: http://tohtml.com/

copy the preview from your browser window and just paste into Word or Outlook.

Comment: The above is a very useful tool. Why isn't this a plugin for gmail/outlook/mail client of your choice yet?

Answer (score 2):

Vim (or GVim) will output your code as formatted HTML. Then as long as your email is using an HTML format you can copy and paste it in.

Comment: how do you tell VIM to do that?

Comment: @Nathan: See the link ive added in the question: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Pasting_code_with_syntax_coloring_in_emails

Comment: @svrist See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65968664/845034.

Answer (score 2):

Just an update on this matter, if you're on Windows, you can install Notepad++ (which is one of the best windows editors anyway), it comes out of the box with a plugin for this: "Copy text with Syntax Highlighting", when you select some text and right click on it.

Comment: Here is how to copy RTF and HTML syntax using Notepad++:  http://superuser.com/a/578059

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the [Add-In here it is](http://www.jtleigh.com/people/colin/software/CopySourceAsHtml/).

If you want to know how it is done, [here is an article on how to write the Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163652.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.fauskes.net/nb/syntaxms/) led me to [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html).

Looks like [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) has a Copy to RTF feature:

[image: SciTE]

Edit(vmware upgrade):
But it looks like I am pretty much lost when I use vmware because I cant transfer rtf clipboard items to the vmware host. And I cant install software on the vmware host.

Maybe a paste-site with syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 1):

Comment: svrist mentioned a code paste site with syntax highlighting. Try http://codepad.org/

(don't have enough mojo to comment yet)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, Visual Studio does this automatically. At least it does for me, using Visual Studio 2005 on XP and copy/pasting to both MS Word and Lotus Notes

Comment: Was about to post the same. Would be overkill to fire up VS just for formatting, but I guess most IDEs will have such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

**HeidiSQL** does this for sql queries, and the syntax highlighting choices they made are quite readable.  However, this will only work for sql queries, not other code.  I like **Notepad++** for Windows-based systems, and [here are some instructions for Notepad++](https://superuser.com/a/578059).  Several people mentioned **VIM** for unix/shell environment.

Answer (score 0):

For **gVim (Windows)**, I defined this function and a convenience mapping:

```
function! HlCopy() range
    exec a:firstline.','.a:lastline.'TOhtml'
    normal yG
    q!
    !start /min powershell "Get-Clipboard | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml"
    redraw
endfun
vmap Y :call HlCopy()<CR>
```

**How to use?**

- Enter visual mode with <kbd>v</kbd> or by selecting text with left mouse. Then copy the current selection as raw text with <kbd>y</kbd> or highlighted text with <kbd>Y</kbd>.
- Pass range directly (without visual mode): `:1,3call HlCopy()`.

If you are lazy like me, you can set additional options for `TOhtml` in that function. I have this in my vimrc:

```
function! HlCopy() range
    let g:html_font = "Consolas"
    let g:html_number_lines = 0
    exec a:firstline.','.a:lastline.'TOhtml'
    normal yG
    q!
    !start /min powershell "Get-Clipboard | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml"
    redraw
endfun
vmap Y :call HlCopy()<CR>
```